# Top K Frequent Elements Leetcode 347

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

With my code whenever there are only two values it can't handle an input of two values. Anything greater than two values has no problem and correctly creates the dictionary. With two values the first set of Key value pairs isn't added to the second dictionary to be flipped for downstream steps.

```
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        dictionary = {} 
        small = {} 
        answer = []
        i = 0
        if len(nums) <= 1:
            return nums
        for number in nums:
            dictionary[number]= 1 + dictionary.get(number,0)
        for key , v in dictionary.items():
            print(key,v)
            // the key value pairs are correctly printed here 
            small[v] = key 
            // yet here if there are only two values in the input (i.e. [1,2])   
             the first set of key value pairs in DICTIONARY {1:1 , 2:1}  won't get added to SMALL yet the                                        
             second pair will, this is where I'm lost
        print(small)
        while i < k:
            count = max(small)
            answer.append(small[count])
            del small[count]
            i +=1 
        return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not specifically about two values. When there is only one of each value, for example if your input is `[1,2,3,4,5]` it will have a similar problem with `small`.

This is because of `small[v] = key` which will be like `small[1] = 1` followed by `small[1] = 2`.
So the value of `small[1]` is replaced whenever you have another `key` that only appears once.